# Ubuntu not upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.10

I have attempted to upgrade my ubuntu system from 18.10 to version 19.04 after being prompted by the system updater.

[image: Image of update prompt]

I clicked upgrade button, and the screen disappeared and my system did not update.

I have even attempted the command line way of solving this after searching google but that also didn't work. Just not sure how I can upgrade because I have tried numerous times and it still hasn't upgraded.

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` in a console and see what's happening. Post the output here...

Comment: `The following packages have been kept back:
  libodbc1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out. I was doing `sudo apt-get upgrade` and a certain package was not being upgraded. So what I did was tried to specifically target that package with `sudo apt-get install libodbc1` and it upgraded it, then I went `sudo do-release-upgrade` and I think its working.